svelte working with HTMLObjectElements seems.. buggy?
i need to embed an svg element in my svelte project.
i am trying to do it like this:
<script>
let svg_path = 'https://microbeatlas.org/media/taxon_env_svgs/cb189.prevalence.90_9.svg';
</script>

<object data={svg_path} type="image/svg+xml" />

now, I would like to add some event listeners to certain Ids (essentially highlighting the corresponding elements in some table somewhere), however svelte seems to resist.
if write the code above I can go to the site and see the element displayed. however if I open the console and type
document.getElementById("prevalence;soil;shrub")

I get null. sometimes this changes if I open the developer tools and hover over the element or something (I don't know what exactly it is). Point is, I have no idea how to consistently get specific elements in the SVG.

when I paste the svg_path directly into the browser to open the SVG, then enter
open the console and type
document.getElementById("prevalence;soil;shrub")

I always get the correct element back.

ChatGpt told me to just fetch(svg_path), but this gives me issues with cors and I cant really change the backend.
edit in reference to a post below:

I sometimes CAN access the SVG element, for example here I clicked at the element I want in the developer tools? and then it can find it.

You can only access the elements if you are within the scope of the SVG document. Check the URL in your screenshots, one is directly referencing the SVG.
If the SVG is static at build time, you can just import the contents and insert them directly into the document, after downloading it first:
<script>
  import svg from './local/path/to/file.svg?raw'; // note query parameter
</script>

{@html svg}

Alternatively add a simple plugin that downloads the file on build, e.g.
function dlRaw() {
  const prefix = `/@dl-raw/`;

  return {
    name: 'dl-raw',
    enforce: 'pre',
    resolveId(source) {
      if (!source.startsWith('dl-raw:'))
        return null;

      return prefix + source.slice('dl-raw:'.length);
    },
    async load(id) {
      if (!id.startsWith(prefix))
        return;

      const url = id.slice(prefix.length);
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const text = await response.text();

      return {
        code: `export default ${JSON.stringify(text)};`,
        map: null,
      };
    },
  };
}

<script>
  import svg from 'dl-raw:https://microbeatlas.org/...';
</script>

(The plugin could be improved by caching files locally during dev.)
If the SVG is not static, you could load it on the server and pass it to the browser:
// +page.server.js
export async function load() {
  const svg = await fetch('https://<...>.svg').then(r => r.text());

  return { svg }
}

<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
  export let data;
</script>

{@html data.svg}

If neither is an option, you would would have to make the SVG available with the necessary CORS headers to allow direct access from the application.

The inserted elements can be accessed in onMount.

The +page.server.ts works beautifully, you can succesfully add your event listeners in the onMount function using document.getElementById("prevalence;soil;shrub").addEventListener("click", function highlightOnSomeTableSomewhere() {}) and it's there when you select the element in the Chrome devTools and do getEventListeners($0).

but i do not know the exact path at build time, it depends on some query params on the client. what does work is the page server example, its what I am working with right now, thank you. still, its curious that sometimes I CAN access the SVG through the object. If I click on inspect ->and then click on the element I want to  access, document.getElementById("prevalence;soil;shrub") will return the correct item. i will update the original post with an image

@david11: The inspector can set the current document context and ignore origins. On inspect it automatically switches to the document owning the element. You can see and change the current context in the dropdown under the "Elements" tab at the top. Note how it does not say "Top" and refers to the document referenced by the <object> (the same applies to <iframe>).
